# RDLC Report- Error Rownumber() can't be used in filter

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have two Tablix(tables) and one dataset.
They are bounding with this dataset

```
   Serial No.  |      Name    
 ______________|________________
    SN0003     |      Beckham
    SN0005     |      Henry
    SN0012     |      Rooney
    SN0119     |      Ji Sung
    SN0200     |      Gerrard
```

In my report, I need to split two tablix 
It will display like below...

(It's "Left to Right"  before "Up to Buttom")

```
   Serial No.  |      Name        ||    Serial No.  |    Name
 ______________|________________  || _______________|______________
    SN0003     |      Beckham     ||     SN0005     |    Henry        
    SN0012     |      Rooney      ||     SN0119     |    Ji Sung
    SN0200     |      Gerrard     ||                |
```

Left table is Tablix1 and
Right table is Tablix2

I think use this FilterExpression for each tablix.

```
      = RowNumber(Nothing) mod 2 = 0
```

for Tablix1(Left table)

```
      = RowNumber(Nothing) mod 2 = 1
```

for Tablix2(Right table)

But it's error this Message...

```
     "A FilterExpression for tablix ‘Tablix1’ uses the RowNumber function.
      RowNumber cannot be used in filters."
```

It's can't use Rownumber in Filter. 
What should I do? Is it possible if I don't edit dataset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it possible for you to edit the dataset that you are reciving in the first place?  You can add a `ROW_NUMBER` field to this by using

```
SELECT
  ...,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SerialNo ASC) AS RowNum,
  ...
```

Then your returned dataset would look like

```
   Serial No.  |      Name      |  RowNum
 ______________|________________|__________
    SN0003     |      Beckham   |   1
    SN0005     |      Henry     |   2
    SN0012     |      Rooney    |   3
    SN0119     |      Ji Sung   |   4
    SN0200     |      Gerrard   |   5
```

And then you can do your filter on `RowNum mod 2 = 0`

**Edit**

Alternatively if you can't change the underlying dataset you can be clever using RunningValue and CountDistinct.

`CountDistinct` will give you the number of rows that match in the dataset, for each row (so, usually 1 assuming Serial Numbers are unique)

`RunningValue` will give you an increasing total of values across each row in a table... and with this you can add up all those `CountDistincts'.

Set the Row Visibility of your table to be something like

For Tablix1

```
=(RunningValue(CountDistinct(Fields!SerialNo.Value), Sum, "DataSetName") mod 2) = 0
```

For Tablix2

```
=(RunningValue(CountDistinct(Fields!SerialNo.Value), Sum, "DataSetName") mod 2) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your replied.And tell you "I'm Sorry".
My team don't want to edit any dataset because It have an affect on another part of project.

Is it possible if I resolve this problem without editng datatable?

Comment: Edited to give solution not editing the underlying SQL

Comment: Thank you very much. It's work .

I make new datatable and clone all data which a new datatable is added seq_no column.

Thanks.

Comment: Jonnus and @ThanapipatPacharatanakoson : Instead of `(RunningValue(CountDistinct(Fields!SerialNo.Value), Sum, "DataSetName") mod 2)` I think you can use `RowNumber(Nothing) mod 2` for the row visibility to get to same result.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] Thanks, Jonas

This my datatable. I created new column for store seq_no.
By Right click>Add column and change name "SEQ_NO"
[image]

Next step, I set a value to SEQ_NO column by codeing with vb

```
                Dim dt As dsProductionControl.TL_PRODUCTION_SCHEDULE_DETAILSDataTable = DsProductionControl.TL_PRODUCTION_SCHEDULE_DETAILS

                For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
                    dt.Rows(i).Item("SEQ_NO") = i
                Next i
```

And set Filter in Tablix of the report by SEQ_NO

```
        =Fields!SEQ_NO.Value Mod 2 = 0
```

Thanks, Jonas again.